# How to use Qt Creator

Tags: qt

I'm not a programmer, I just want to get pdf4qt working so I can see if it's a decent pdf editor for Debian Buster. I opened it and tried to configure and got the following:

```
    Running "/usr/local/bin/cmake /home/Rob/Downloads/PDF4QT-1.3.1 '-GCodeBlocks - Ninja' -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=/usr -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake" in /tmp/QtCreator-fjypKO/qtc-cmake-tKrZfijV.
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:46 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt6.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt6Config.cmake
    qt6-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt6" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt6_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt6" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/QtCreator-fjypKO/qtc-cmake-tKrZfijV/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
*** cmake process exited with exit code 1.
```

Is someone able to tell me in layman's terms what this means?

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the instructions [from github, step 6](https://github.com/JakubMelka/PDF4QT#6-compiling)? Also I'm not really sure but it seems you are using a `gcc` version below the required, the program was tested on `GCC 11.2.0`  and it seems you are using the version `8.3.0`, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Since the build of your app is apparently handled by qtcreator, it'll be hard to tell you "in layman's terms". To begin with the most probable : your QT6 environment has not been completely configured. This should normally be done when installing qt-creator via your package manager. So How did you install qt-creator ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @EdgarMagallon, I tried to follow step 6, it was Qt creator which produced the output which I pasted in the OP. Am I able to upgrade GCC to 11 in debian Buster? Or is my distro too old?

Comment: @MC68020 I think I just used apt-get to install Qt creator. How can I configure it appropriately? Thanks!

Comment: @1toneboy I'm not sure if you have that package in your debian repositories. Try install it with: `sudo apt install gcc-11`